# Jquery Mobile - second click sometimes does not highlight nav-button

Tags: jquery, mobile

I am creating my first JQuery Mobile app. I have the following html:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
        //  $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
        //  $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
            $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
        });
    </script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- INDEX - TOP -->
<div data-role="page" id="pg-index">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>APP</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h3 id="db-title">Add Client</h3>
    </div><!-- /content -->

   <div data-role="footer">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="grid" class="ui-btn-active">Summary</a></li>
                <li><a href="#pg-settings" data-ajax="false" data-icon="gear">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#pg-about" data-ajax="false" data-icon="info">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->
<!-- INDEX - BOTTOM -->

<!-- SETTINGS - TOP -->
<div data-role="page" id="pg-settings">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>APP</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h3 class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">Settings</h3>
        <form>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" id="ss-ctrl-units">
                    <legend>
                        Units of Measurement:
                    </legend>
                    <input name="ctrl-units-1" id="ctrl-units-1" value="metric" checked="checked" type="radio">
                    <label for="ctrl-units-1">Metric</label>
                    <input name="ctrl-units-1" id="ctrl-units-2" value="imperial" type="radio">
                    <label for="ctrl-units-2">Imperial</label>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <div id="sg-Metric" class="hide-object-none">
                <p>Data will be displayed and recorded in metric units.</p>
                <p>Examples:</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Height: 182 cm (one-hundred and eighty-two centimeters)</li>
                    <li>Weight: 85.22 kg (eighty-five kilograms)</li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <div id="sg-Imperial" class="hide-object-none">
                <p>Data will be displayed and recorded in imperial units.</p>
                <p>Examples:</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Height: 5'4" (five feet, four inches)</li>
                    <li>Weight: 154 lb (one-hundred and fifty-found pounds)</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" data-ajax="false" data-icon="grid">Summary</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-active">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#pg-about" data-ajax="false" data-icon="info">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->
<!-- SETTINGS - BOTTOM -->

<!-- ABOUT - TOP -->
<div data-role="page" id="pg-about">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>APP</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        about stuff
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" data-ajax="false" data-icon="grid">Summary</a></li>
                <li><a href="#pg-settings" data-ajax="false" data-icon="gear">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="info" class="ui-btn-active">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->
<!-- ABOUT - BOTTOM -->
</body>
```

I have checked StackOverflow already. The closest problem similar to mine I could find is [Jquery Mobile Button is not working at Second Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972261/jquery-mobile-button-is-not-working-at-second-click). I could not find any duplicate IDs in my pages. Unless I'm not looking carefully enough...

Active Button Scenarios that Work:
Summary to Settings / Settings to Summary. Highlighting works - Settings is Highlighted.
Summary to Settings. Then click Settings (again). Highlighting works - Settings is Highlighted.
Summary to About / About to Summary. Highlighting works - Summary is Highlighted.
Summary to About. Then click About (again). Highlighting works - About is Highlighted.

Active Buttons Scenarios that Do Not Work:
Summary to Settings to About to Settings. The Settings button should be highlighted. It is not.
Summary to About to Settings to About. The About button should be highlighted. It is not.

Question: how to fix the scenarios that do not work?

Comment: if you're down voting, please at least explain why.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this out: add "ui-state-persist" class to the active button. This will ensure the active setting remains active. Hidden in plain site on http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navbar/.